# Rails ActiveRecord conditionally protect an attribute from modification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, attributes, readonly

I have a `Message` model with a `content` attribute (string) and a `sent` attribute (boolean). A **message's `content` should be modifiable until it's been sent, after which that field should become read only.** (Other attributes can still be modifiable, such as `message_opened`).

How can I accomplish this? I've looked into overriding `readonly?` (only applies at the record level), `attr_readonly` (not conditional), and validations (don't know how to make the validation of the `content` depend on both its old value and the `sent` field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out validations are the right approach: create a custom validation that uses `attribute_changed?` ("attribute" is the name of the attribute, in this case, "content") and a conditional validation.

Message.rb:

```
validate_on_update :reject_modifying_content, if: :sent?

def reject_modifying_content
 errors[:content] << "can not be changed!" if self.content_changed?
end
```

See [Rails 3 check if attribute changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051135/rails-3-check-if-attribute-changed), [Setting a field to read-only in Rails after it's created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798309/setting-a-field-to-read-only-in-rails-after-its-created) and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Going over possible answers, I think setting the field as:

```
attr_readonly
```

Is the best option is it will totally protect that field without custom code needed.

> Attributes listed as readonly will be used to create a new record but
>   update operations will ignore these fields.